# CUDA Expression Templates and Just in Time Compilation (JIT)

Tags: dll, cuda, expression, jit, ptx

I have some questions about Just-In-Time (JIT) compilation with CUDA.

I have implemented a library based on Expression Templates according to the paper

J.M. Cohen, "Processing Device Arrays with C++ Metaprogramming", GPU Computing Gems - Jade Edition

It seems to work fairly good. If I compare the computing time of the matrix elementwise operation

D_D=A_D*B_D-sin(C_D)+3.;

with that of a purposely developed CUDA kernel, I have the following results (in parentheses, the matrix size):

time [ms] hand-written kernel: 2.05 (1024x1024) 8.16 (2048x2048) 57.4 (4096*4096)

time [ms] LIBRARY: 2.07 (1024x1024) 8.17 (2048x2048) 57.4 (4096*4096)

The library seems to need approximately the same computing time of the hand-written kernel. I'm also using the C++11 keyword auto to evaluate expressions only when they are actually needed, according to [Expression templates: improving performance in evaluating expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15856122/expression-templates-improving-performance-in-evaluating-expressions). My first question is

*1. Which kind of further benefit (in terms of code optimization) would JIT provide to the library? Would JIT introduce any further burdening due to runtime compilation?*

It is known that a library based on Expression Templates cannot be put inside a .dll library, see for example http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/00edbe1d-4906-4d91-b710-825b503787e2. My second question is:

*2. Would JIT help in hiding the implementation to a third-party user? If yes, how?*

The CUDA SDK include the ptxjit example in which the ptx code is not loaded at runtime, but defined at compile time. My third question is:

*3. How should I implement JIT in my case? Are there examples of JIT using PTX loaded at runtime?*

Thank you very much for any help.

**EDIT following Talonmies' comment**

From the [Cuda kernel just-in-time (jit) compilation possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13567123/cuda-kernel-just-in-time-jit-compilation-possible) post, it reads that

> cuda code can be compiled to an intermediate format ptx code, which will then be jit-compiled to the actual device architecture machine code at runtime

A doubt I have is whether the above can be applied to an Expression Templates library. I know that, due to instantiation problems, a CUDA/C++ template code cannot be compiled to a PTX. But perhaps if I instantiate all the possible combinations of Type/Operators for Unary and Binary Expressions, at least a part of the implementation can be compiled (and then masked to third-party users) to PTX which can be in turn JIT compiled to the architecture at hand.

Comment: I got lost when you suddenly jumped from C++ metaprogramming to just in time compilation of PTX assembly. There seems to be some fairly major missing elements between the two. How will C++ template code get JIT compiled to PTX?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I edited my post trying to better explain the problem. My problem is mainly to hide the implementation (or a part of the implementation) and to improve the performance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look into [OpenCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL). It provides a JIT-like programming model for creating, compiling, and executing compute kernels on GPUs (all at run-time).

I take a similar, expression-template based approach in [Boost.Compute](https://github.com/kylelutz/compute) which allows the library to support C++ templates and generic algorithms by translating compile-type C++ expressions into OpenCL kernel code (which is a dialect of C).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But, could I "port" your answer to CUDA? In your experience, does JIT provide a further benefit or a further burdening due to runtime compilation?

Answer (score -1):

[VexCL](https://github.com/ddemidov/vexcl) started as an expression template library for OpenCL, but since v1.0 it also supports CUDA. What it does for CUDA is exactly JIT-compilation of CUDA sources. `nvcc` compiler is called behind the scenes, the compiled PTX is stored in an offline cache and is loaded on subsequent launches of the program. See [CUDA backend sources](https://github.com/ddemidov/vexcl/tree/master/vexcl/backend) for how to do this. [compiler.hpp](https://github.com/ddemidov/vexcl/blob/master/vexcl/backend/cuda/compiler.hpp) should probably be of most interest for you.